# "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var" when trying to write a small piece of code for comparing the properties of 2 objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I wrote the following code to compare the properties of 2 objects -  object1 and object2.

```
var object1 = {1:"abc",2:"def"};
var object2 = {1:"abc",2:"def"};
for (var prop in object1) {
    if (!(var prop in object2)) {
        console.log("fail");
  }
}
```

However, I get the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var".

I was trying to emulate bits of the following code, which was written for comparing different objects, and returning true if they have identical contents.

```
function deepEqual(a, b) {
  if (a === b) return true;

  if (a == null || typeof a != "object" ||
      b == null || typeof b != "object")
    return false;

  var propsInA = 0, propsInB = 0;

  for (var prop in a)
    propsInA += 1;

  for (var prop in b) {
    propsInB += 1;
    if (!(prop in a) || !deepEqual(a[prop], b[prop]))
      return false;
  }

  return propsInA == propsInB;
}

var obj = {here: {is: "an"}, object: 2};
console.log(deepEqual(obj, obj));
// → true
console.log(deepEqual(obj, {here: 1, object: 2}));
// → false
console.log(deepEqual(obj, {here: {is: "an"}, object: 2}));
// → true
```

Specifically, the part that I was trying to emulate is the the following section of code which compares the properties of 2 objects.

```
for (var prop in b) {
        propsInB += 1;
        if (!(prop in a) || !deepEqual(a[prop], b[prop]))
          return false;
      }
```

Can someone please help explain why the code I wrote didn't work while the original code worked?

And if my understanding of the original code is wrong, how should I have written my code to compare the properties of 2 objects (emulating the original code I took inspiration from)?

Thanks for your help and advice!

Comment: Remove the two var keywords from the for...in loop and the if statement

Comment: if (!(var prop in object2)) remove var from this

Comment: I tried what you said and it works now! But why did the original code have the 2 var keywords?

Comment: @SailorLeroy: You can have the var statement in the `for...in` loop if you wanted to have that variable only for the scope of the `for`. It looks like that's the case here.

Comment: @Rachel, the `var` statement in the `for...in` loop declares that variable only for the duration of that loop (its scope). Once the loop is over, that variable does not exist anymore and is no longer available. You cannot put a variable declaration in an if-statement. You can use the `in` (in an if statement) operator to check if a key exists in an object or array.

Comment: @SamT that was a very helpful explanation! now i get it, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't declare a `var` in an `if`:

```
if (!(var prop in object2)) {  // error
    console.log("fail");
}
```

Alternatively, this asks if the property `prop` does not exist in `object2`, which is probably what was meant:

```
if (!(prop in object2)) {
    console.log("fail");
}
```